# django-haystack: Autocomplete for postgres hstore

Tags: django, postgresql, django-haystack

Model index code:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  ...
  # We add this for autocomplete.
  content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
```

"title" field in our case is hstore field of postgres db. Autocomplete doesn't work with this field, it works if we use any charfield in place of hstore(Regular search works with hstore, but autocomplete feature we're not able to use).

Let us know any solution for this ??

Comment: Not sure about haystacks autocomplete, but I used typeahead.js and it mostly works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443644/remote-autocomplete-by-typeahead-works-only-on-unique-queries